"GPIO busy" How to use the same gpio pin in separate processes?
I had a Pi Zero.  I broke it and the SD card, then bought a Pi Zero 2 and installed raspbian v 12 (bookworm).
Now when I try to import devs.py in separate processes, I get lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'.
devs.py:
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
    
devs = (
    OutputDevice(2),
    OutputDevice(3),
)

shell.py:
import code
import devs

code.interact(local={ 'devs': devs })

The daemon that starts at boot via /etc/rc.local:
import devs

while True:
    do_something()

This is extremely inconvenient.  Now every time I need to ssh into the pi and open a shell, I have to comment out the rc.local file and reboot.
I never had this problem when I was using the Pi Zero, so it must have something to do with configuration or the newer OS install.
How can I import devs.py in separate, running processes?

WHY would anyone use an obsolete SysV tool rc.local on a systemd OS? What is do_something()?

Perhaps use a different backend for gpiozero.  lgpio uses the /dev/gpiochip interface to the GPIO rather than the deprecated sysfs interface.  The /dev/gpiochip interface only allows one process to access a GPIO at any one time.
Both RPi.GPIO and pigpio should work as backends on a Pi Zero.
